# Partition Error when uploading to CosmosDB from CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, azure-cosmosdb, crm, azure-logic-apps, power-automate

**Background:**

I have set up my LogicApp and everything appears to work fine except when I try to upload back to CosmosDB from CRM.

**This is what I have done so far:**
[image]

**The problem appears to happen here:**
[image]

[image]

**error:**

["PartitionKey extracted from document doesn't match the one specified in the header"]

I have placed the partition within the dynamic field so I am unsure why I am getting this error:

**My partition ID is
OwnerInCRM**

[image]

The partitionkey in which I plan to send my data to is:

**OwnerInCRM**

[image]

**My dilemma/question:**

Why am I getting this partition error when I am putting the correct value in the partition key value field? (OwnerInCRM)

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your screenshot of your container,your Partition key is OwnerInCRM.However your OwnerInCRM value in your document is `""`,and your Partition key value is not same with `""`,which leads to your error.(your Partition key value should be same to your OwnerInCRM value,not value of your id)

Please try this,set both your Partition key value and OwnerInCRM value is `Richard`.

Comment: Ok I will try. I believe my partition value does have the “” though...?

Comment: Wow this worked and I have a much better understanding of this now. Thank you tremendously! Do you happen to know about how to update lookup fields within CRM? I just posted this. I am still researching this and any help is appreciated. Thank you Steve!!

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with that.sry.

Comment: Thank you for the knowledge on this question!